# Omnifaces Socket doesn't work on https connection

Tags: jsf, glassfish, omnifaces, java-websocket

recently i was exploring websocket and i choose to use using `<o:socket>` from Omnifaces, I'm using Glassfish 4 for the server i have test and run my code on localhost and its working and perfectly fine, but the problem is when i upload to server which using `HTTPS` connection it's doesn't work, when i want open the connection it's failed and give me error `1006` , so i suspect the problem is on `HTTP` or `HTTPS` is there configuration i need to run websocket on `HTTPS`?

Comment: You get error 1006, did you google "websocket error 1006"? Google itself will tell you *"Close Code 1006 is a special code that means the connection was closed abnormally (locally) by the browser implementation. If your browser client reports close code 1006 , then you should be looking at the websocket. onerror(evt) event for details"*, in other words how to get more error details that you could either use to figure out the problem, or ask a better question. The omnifaces documentation shows how to do it.

Comment: So GlassFish itself is not using HTTPS but still HTTP? So the websocket URL being generated is ws:// instead of wss://?

Comment: GlassFish already using HTTPS, and when i look into error on console log browser, it's using wss (Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://) @BalusC